# Adding multiple links to the same table cell

Tags: 8

I am struggling to add multiple links to the same table cell, my current code looks like:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;

$row[] = [
  'data' => Link::createFromRoute(...),
  'class' => 'middle',
];
$row[] = [
  'data' => Link::createFromRoute(...),
  'class' => 'middle',
];
$rows[] = ['data' => $row, 'no_striping' => TRUE];

return [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => [..],
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

I've cut down the code to the relevant parts each element of the `$row` variable is a new cell and each element of the `$rows` variable is a new row. I need to use the data attribute as I have additional attributes on the cell.

At present this works perfectly fine, but my links are rendered in separate cells and I would like them rendered in the same cell. If I just to concatenate the 2 `Link::createFromRoute` I get the following error:

`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Link could not be converted to string`

I've tried using the `toString()` and the `toRenderable()` functions and neither work as I want. Surely it can't be that hard?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you should only add one cell to the row, and make its `data` a render array containing the two links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it as Clive alluded to with render array:

```
  $link_1 = Link::createFromRoute('Link 1', 'route_1')->toString();
  $link_2 = Link::createFromRoute('Link 2', 'route_2')->toString();
  $link_concat = ['#markup' => $link_1 . ' - ' . $link_2];

  $header = [ ... ];
  $row = [];
  $row[] = [
    'data' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($link_concat),
    'class' => 'middle',
  ];
return [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => [..],
  '#rows' => $row,
];
```

This is just one method of doing it, there are a lot of ways you could potentially work this scenario. This way just puts the two links with a dash in between. But hopefully this will help guide you towards a solution.

Comment: This works, I tried ->toString() but didn't then add them to a #markup render array